# Git: How to reintroduce former deletions or how to merge parent into child commit

Tags: git, git-merge

Suppose I have a linear `git` history

```
A-B-C-...-X (HEAD)
          ↑
        master
```

Now I noticed, that I deleted some lines in `C` that were present in `B` and that I want to restore. It is possible to just copy everything manually or apply a patch. But I want the tree to look something like

```
    -------
   /       \
A-B-C-...-X-Y (HEAD)
            ↑
          master
```

to make the changes more apparent. I tried to merge using

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit --no-ff B
```

but `git` only tells me that everything is "already up to date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no user-oriented command to do what you'd like.  You *can* do exactly that, somewhat manually.  For instance:

```
git diff <hash-of-A> <hash-of-B> | git apply
# make sure it looks right
git add <files>    # as desired
tree=$(git write-tree)
vim /tmp/message   # or other editor of choice
commit=$(git commit-tree -p HEAD -p <hash-of-B> -F /tmp/message $tree)
git log --graph --decorate --oneline $commit  # make sure you like it
git merge --ff-only $commit
# then clean up etc
```

You can shrink this down to just a few commands using nested `$(...)` sequences.

Most people, however, just prefer to use `git cherry-pick`, perhaps with `-x`.  Note that `git cherry-pick -n` lets you do the equivalent of the diff-and-apply sequence and may make the above more convenient: I chose the diff-and-apply sequence more for illustration.

The `git write-tree; git commit-tree; git merge --ff-only` sequence is roughly how `git commit` itself actually works, except that `git commit` is much fancier, and doesn't let you specify the individual parents.

Another approach is to use `git checkout <hash-of-A>; git cherry-pick <hash-of-B>` to make a new commit `B'`, then use `git merge` to merge this new `B'` commit.  (Save its hash for your `git merge`, or do this on a temporary branch that you delete after the merge, so that you don't need to fuss with raw hash IDs.)  The result looks like this instead of what you've drawn:

```
  ------B'------
 /              \
A--B--C--...--X--Y   <-- master (HEAD)
```

This may be clearer to some future viewer than the weird manually-constructed merge.

Comment: It fails in applying the patch. How do I work around this?

Comment: Usually that means that the A-to-B change is more than you want. You have many options: slim down the diff; do the change manually; use `git apply --reject` and hand edit the results; use `git cherry-pick` or `git apply -3` to get three-way merge involved; and so on.

Comment: Ok, I just managed to go through all commands and it precisely does what I want. I noticed however, that you missed the non-optional `$(tree)` parameter on the line `commit=$(...)`. It would be great if you fixed it.

Comment: @xwst Oops! fixed